# Taking the backup of EC2 Root volume while the instance is running

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to take the snapshot of all the EC2 instances. I am confused how to take the snapshot of the volume that is mounted as root? Should I shut down the instance before taking the snapshot of root volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have and EBS-backed instance, to create a snapshot for an EBS volume that serves as the root device, you should *stop* the instance before taking the snapshot.

See [Creating an Amazon EBS Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)

Comment: And what if stopping is not an option?

Comment: I know its been 7 years, but even though its recommended to stop the instance, in my experience the process works just fine with the instance running. Maybe a tad slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you shutdown all machines and after take snapshots thats the much better, if not affect your infrastructure.

use the that link for create snapshot http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html
you can create a script.like this as you can better..
all_instance_ids=`ec2-describe-instances | grep INSTANCE | grep running | sort -k10 | cut -f2`
for i in ${all_instance_ids}
do
  ec2-create-snapshot ${i}
done